# How to install 32 bit MS office 2010 on ubuntu 16.04 , 64 bit, with wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine, microsoft-office

How to install 32 bit MS office 2010 on ubuntu 16.04 , 64 bit, with Wine?Should I install "64 bit" MS Office on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit?
Are there any problems using MS Office on Ubuntu?

Comment: You are far better off using Libreoffice. Ubuntu / Linux is not a drop in replacement for windows and wine can not reliably run windows apps.

Comment: See also https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/539061/how-to-install-microsoft-office-2010-in-ubuntu-with-wine/

Answer (score 0):

Although WINE is good at running windows apps, there are limitations.
Office is particularly fussy, especially Publisher.

http://winehq.org has a data base of setups for various applications.

For a 32-bit Office you will need a 32-bit wine prefix, and I would recommend using an older version of Office. Office2007 has the new file formats and probably has a better success in wine.

Office 2005 and older do not have the new formats but have an even better chance at success in wine.

Comment: the *"new file formats"* in each version of MS Office are NOT the same! ...as you can easily see in [this table (german)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Interoperabilit%C3%A4t). so i would recommend using MS Office 2013 or newer, if it has to be MS Office - using LibreOffice would be the better solution. -- and finally i would strongly advise to neither use nor install MS Ofiice 2007 or older, because support & updates are no more available since october 2017!

Comment: @DJCrashdummy 2013, 2010, 2007 use the same format https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797428.aspx

Comment: you are talking about 3 different formats which all use the same extension (e.g. docx, xlsx,...)! - as you can read in your link compared to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797428(v=office.14).aspx, only MS Office 2013 (and up) fully supports the ISO/IEC 29500 conform OOXML-Strict. MS Office 2010 only supports OOXML-Transitional and MS Office 2007 uses "Ecma Office Open XML".

Comment: ...i would anyway advise to use [ODF 1.2 (ISO/IEC 26300)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) - also fully supported since MS Office 2013 - which is supported by a [variety of programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_software), so you can always easily switch between any of them.